# join() got multiple values for argument 'path'

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a path with `os.path.join`, but I get `TypeError: join() got multiple values for argument 'path'`.  How do I fix this error?

```
path = os.path.join('posts', path=POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION)
```

Comment: Just remove the `path=` in front of `POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION`. `path` is already the name of the first argument.

Comment: wow, thanks man, I've been digging the internet for an hour... But can you please tell me why some people use that path argument and works for them?  I've been watching a lot of tutorials lately.
GOT IT PATH IS THE NAME OF 1st ARGUMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `os.path.join()` without `path` as key argument:

```
os.path.join('posts', POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION)
```